# How to reject email from unknown domains with Postfix on CentOS

Tags: centos, postfix

**CentOS 7

Version = 2.10.1**

How can I configure postfix mail server from excepting emails from spoofed addresses, so if someone sends an email **FROM** `admin@99999999yabadabadoo.com`, postfix will reject the email because the domain `99999999yabadabadoo.com` does not exist.

When I place

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
```

inside my `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and I send an email from my from  `myemail.gmail.com` account, it gets rejected with the error message:

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[209.85.222.180]: 450 4.1.8 <myemail@gmail.com>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found; from=<myemail@gmail.com> to=<myotheremail@myhosted-domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-qk1-f180.google.com>.
```

My dns is setup correctly. I can dig, nslookup and host the ip 209.85.222.180 correctly. Would it matter that I have many ips on the box and I ind each ip to a specific mail.domain.com and don't use the first first ip of the box for anything other than the box hostname? I receive email correctly to 8 domains I have hosted on this machine.

**Update:** Running dig google.com MX to retrieve the set of MX records. Then running nslookup and dig to the hostname given by the MX records to get the IP addresses.

[image: Running dig google.com MX to retrieve the set of MX records.]

So sometimes the ips match and sometimes they don't.

Answer (score 1):

You activate restriction(s) of your choice for incoming email with Postfix `main.cf` parameter [`smtpd_sender_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions).

In particular, you'll probably want at least `reject_unknown_sender_domain` in there: it rejects the incoming email if there is either a malformed MX record for the sender in the DNS, or neither A nor MX records exist in the DNS for the sender.

Optionally, you could choose to make a stronger test: attempt to connect to the sender's mail server (i.e. the server indicated by the MX or A record corresponding to the sender's domain name) and see if it would at least tentatively seem to accept mail back to the original sender, or not, and cache the test result for a while. The sender not having a mail server at all would count as failing this test. This would be `reject_unverified_sender`, but it has a few drawbacks: [read the documentation](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html) before enabling it.

Comment: Check my op. I had to add ```When I place``` and below as it was too much info for a comment.

Comment: That was exactly the correct way to add extra information to the question. But if you run `dig google.com MX`, do you get a valid set of MX records back? Can you run nslookup or dig to the addresses mentioned by the MX records and get IP addresses? Since Google uses different servers for different regions in a global load-balancing system, what I see in DNS for Google isn't necessarily same thing your server sees.

Comment: I did as you asked and if you see my op, I added an image that shows the results.

Comment: That looks exactly like a DNS-based load balancer in effect. Google has a system that is monitoring the load on a number of front-end servers, and constantly updating the A records to have the least-loaded server in the first MX slot. The DNS records have a really short TTL, so any changes will take effect in two minutes or so on average. But it looks like the specific way Google has implemented it is making the classic DNS-based sender domain check trickier to  do.